# The method nextline() is undefined for the type Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, case-sensitive

I am trying to understand what it means and why it is wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Relevent {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( x.nextline());
    }
}
```

The Eclipse IDE tells me this is wrong and gives this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method nextline() is undefined for the type Scanner
    at Relevent.main(Relevent.java:9)
```

Comment: can u provide full stack trace

Comment: it is `nextLine()` in camel case actually

Comment: Its L not l try this x.nextLine();

Comment: Eclipse already has auto-completion and code-suggestions. Both are extremely helpful to avoid such mistakes. Use them ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about writing [`x.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())? Java is a case-sensitive language.
You must follow API exactly as written there.

The method name `nextline` looks not understandable/obvious, doesn't it? So, the best practice in Java programming is writing all names in camel case style (except for `final` and `static` variables, e.g. `MY_FINAL_VARIABLE`).

Comment: Alright, I will try to pay attention to case sensitivity a little better. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The method is called `nextLine` (note the upper case L) not `nextline` (all lowercase). You must pay attention to the case of things like method names as they must be exactly right.

Eclipse is showing you that you have a compilation error. If you try to run a program which contains compilation errors it will fail with the 'Unresolved compilation problem:' message that you are getting.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to be more wary of case sensitivity now.